# Alfresco Lucene search results via Java API differ from results in Nodebrowser

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I use Alfresco 4.1 with Lucene enabled. I have a folder of type 'myfoldertype' and named 'one two'. Tokenization on the name is (by default) enabled.
I search by name on a specific type of folder, via my own Java backed webscript. Like this:

```
SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
sp.addStore(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE);
sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE);
sp.setQuery("TYPE:\"mymodel:myfoldertype\" AND @cm\\:name:*one*"
```

I run this query in the authentication context of a user with AuthenticationUtil.runas(). The user has read-access to this folder.

Now, the resultset contains 0 results.

But if I copy/paste the query from the log into the Nodebrowser (in Lucene mode), it DOES return the expected folder.

What could cause this difference? Obviously I would like to get the expected folder in the resultset in my webscript as well.

Comment: I appears to be caused by the use of different locales. My code is running in an EN-locale, whereas the Nodebrowsers was running in NL-locale. I'll investigate further and try to answer the question fully.

Comment: how to get name of alfresco by default parameter.??
E.X. User in Alfresco have first name ,last name and email id,so i want to find particular user through emailId via lucene query so...

Comment: Umang, I think you should a new thread for your question, and elaborate on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you're not escaping the `\` properly

So `@cm\:name:*one*` should be `@cm\\:name:*one*`

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted the query from the log, where the escape-backslashes are already evaluated. They are actually there in the Java code. I corrected the example.

Answer (score 2):

The cause was that my webscript was running under the (JVM default) locale of en-US, but the Nodebrowser was running under the UI locale nl-NL. The cm:name property is of datatype d:text, which has different analyzers for en (AlfrescoStandardAnalyzer) and nl (DutchAnalyzer).

I changed the webscript to use the nl locale and now it returns the same results as the Nodebrowser:

```
import org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.I18NUtil;
...
I18NUtil.setLocale(new Locale("nl"));
return searchService.query(sp);
```